# Task WhenAll exception

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have to execute about 10 tasks and then obtain their results (all different). I have created a wrapper to catch the exceptions, I don't want to know which one failed, but if a failure it should not continue. I also use WhenAll for this, but the problem is that then I get the results of each one and I get an unhandled exception, is there no way not to continue if there are any exceptions from my wrapper?

```
 var 1Task = api.1TaskAsync();
 var 2Task = api.2TaskAsync();
 var 3Task = api.3TaskAsync();

await taskService.RunSafeAsync(() => Task.WhenAll(1Task, 2Task, 3Task));

var result = await 1Task;  <-------------exception
```

TaskService:

```
public async Task RunSafeAsync(Func<Task> task) 
{ 
    try 
    {           
        await task();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to interrupt/cancel all tasks just after the first exception in any of these tasks?

Comment: await taskService.RunSafeAsync (() => Task.WhenAll (1Task, 2Task, 3Task));

if any exceptions occur above, I don't want it to continue with it
var result = await 1Task

Do I have to return any true or false in RunSafeTask?

Comment: The `RunSafeAsync` method doesn't look very safe to me, because it swallows exceptions! If this is intentional, then probably a better name for the method would be `WhenAllNoThrow`. In which case I would question the usefulness of this method. You could just use `try`/`catch` directly on the calling site: `try { await Task.WhenAll(Task1, Task2, Task3); } catch { return; }`. As a side note it's illegal to have variable names starting with numbers in C#.

Comment: The RunSafeAsync snippet is just a part of my code, it's not complete, and the variable names are just an example to make it faster, I know they violate the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve the result from a function that has faulted. It doesn't *have* a result-- because it never finished. Attempting to retrieve its result (as you are) is going to throw an exception, because there is nothing to assign to the variable that is supposed to accept the return value.

To avoid this, check if the task is faulted before attempting to retrieve the result.

```
var 1Task = api.1TaskAsync();
var 2Task = api.2TaskAsync();
var 3Task = api.3TaskAsync();

await taskService.RunSafeAsync(() => Task.WhenAll(1Task, 2Task, 3Task));

if (!1Task.IsFaulted)
{
    var result = await 1Task;
```

Comment: Great answer! I'd just replace `await 1Task` with `1Task.Result` because it was already awaited and result is ready.

Comment: Task.Result, can't bring trouble?

Comment: @angelru not in this case. It's bad idea if task wasn't awaited and Result property doesn't have value yet. But after awaiting, Result propery will just return without blocking

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to *not* continue if there was an exception in any of the methods then don't wrap `WhenAll` and react if it throws.

```
try 
{
   await Task.WhenAll(...);
   // None of the tasks threw an exception;
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // One or more tasks threw an exception 
  return / throw / etc. 
}

//Continue the happy path
```

## Cancellation token

If you need to attempt tasks simultaneously and abort all tasks if one fails than you'll need to look at the cancellation token and activate the token if any exceptions occur (not in the `catch` for whole `WhenAll`, but each tasks would have to be executed in a `try..catch`).

## Maybe sequentially?

BTW. With `.WhenAll` all tasks will be attempted. Maybe you actually want to execute the tasks in sequence and continue only if there are not exceptions:

```
try 
{
    await F1();
    await F2();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

This doesn't seem slick but it makes it very clear that task 2 will not run unless task 1 is a success.

Comment: the idea is to have a try and catch wrapper to pass to all my tasks without putting it in various parts of my application

Comment: I would upvoted this answer, if not for the "Maybe foreach?" section. Starting multiple tasks and awaiting them one by one is destined to result in fire-and-forget tasks. Which is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Fair point. I wrote the snipped for tasks that are not started, but that's not common. I rewrote the section and clarified what I meant by it.